# Kivy custom widget behaving differently when used in box layout

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

I was trying to make an window with two block with vertical box layout, with upper widget larger than lower one. But rather than that, the widgets are stacking on top of other at the bottom left corner, both being of same size.

Here is my code

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.codeinput import CodeInput
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.button import Button

Window.maximize()

class Editor(Widget):
    def __init__(self, *arg, **kwarg):
        super(Editor, self).__init__(*arg, **kwarg)
        self.size_hint= (1, 0.8)
        self.add_widget(Button(text= "1"))

class Output(Widget):
    def __init__(self, *arg, **kwarg):
        super(Output, self).__init__(*arg, **kwarg)
        self.size_hint= (1, 0.2)
        self.add_widget(Button(text= "2"))

class IDE(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, *arg, **kwarg):
        super(IDE, self).__init__(*arg, **kwarg)
        self.orientation= "vertical"
        box1= Editor()
        self.add_widget(box1)
        box2=  Output()
        self.add_widget(box2)


class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return IDE()

if __name__=="__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

(The buttons are used in Output and Editor class just to check their respective parent widget position in resultant window)

Someone help me to figure out what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Editor and Output behave as expected, but are completely invisible. What you are seeing are their own child widgets, the two Buttons, each of which has no position or size applied to it and so takes the default of pos (0, 0) and size (100, 100).

Make the Editor and Output classes some kind of layout, e.g. FloatLayout, or simply remove them and add the Buttons directly to the BoxLayout.